# Can I use the same bootstrap input successful background check image icon in another element to show success?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Problem** the checks displayed in my form (pic below) are all the same except one (birthday) which is a font awesome check I created while the others are bootstrap input form-control 'is-valid' checks.

**QUESTION** - Is there a way to use the bootstrap background image url check icon for my birthday check instead of the font awesome check so that all the checks are the same? If so how would I do that?

ex. replace this font awesome check

```html
<div class="birthday">
  <i *ngIf="age >= 18" class="fa fa-check float-right text-yb" style="margin-right: .5rem;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

with something like this

```css
// this is from the debugger when looking at the green check
.form-control.is-valid, .was-validated .form-control:valid {
    border-color: #008489 !important;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath fill='rgb(0, 132, 137)' d='M2.3 6.73L.6 4.53c-.4-1.04.46-1.4 1.1-.8l1.1 1.4 3.4-3.8c.6-.63 1.6-.27 1.2.7l-4 4.6c-.43.5-.8.4-1.1.1z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
}
```

```html
<span class="form-control is-valid">check icon here</span>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want the green border around the 'Birthday' text also?

Comment: Would something like this work?
https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-herschel-2m4c8?file=/src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Ya that does give me the check, but the padding and margins are all messed up now from the check.

Comment: Well, try posting the form markup, so that we have a clear view of the layout and the elements.

Comment: I figured it out.

Comment: Great! It would be of great help to share your solution as an answer, with the community. @ user1186050

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did.

```
<label [ngClass]="age >= 18 ? 'is-valid' : ''" style="margin-bottom: 0px; color: #212529" class="border-0 form-control pl-0">Birthday</label>
```